# Custom permissions on viewset

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework, http-method

Im trying to find a way to create custom permissions on a viewset.
Im want to implement somthing like this :

```
class ActivityViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Activity.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ActivitySerializer
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        permission_classes = (permissions.IsOwner)
    elif request.method == 'LIST':
        permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdmin)
    else :
        permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny)
```

IE : sorting permissions by method. (the above code doesnt work cause "request" isnt recognized)

Couldn't find any use in the "Custom permissions" section of the documentation, but maybe Im just blind. (overriding BasePermission? how? who? where?)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Viewsets use `action` to determine HTTP a verb and permissions invoked from `get_permissions` method, so you can override it:

```
class ActivityViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Activity.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ActivitySerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == 'update':
            return IsOwner()
        elif self.action == 'list':
            return IsAdminUser()
        else :
            return AllowAny()
```

Comment: Actually, had a little problem with it. 'IsAdminUser()' is not recognized which brings a NameError.

Comment: any chance you know why thats happening?

Comment: @idik yes `IsAdmin` is wrong name for permission, there is `IsAdminUser`. Here is all default permissions classes http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/

Comment: Yep :) ended up using some other code from here (pretty similar stuff): 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283797/django-rest-framework-add-additional-permission-in-viewset-update-method

Comment: I tried testing this with `AllowAny()` and it gave me `'AllowAny' object is not iterable`

Comment: I found the reason...the permissions classes have to be in a list

Answer (score 3):

Spent some amount on the same problem. Here is the solution for DRF 3+

```
class ActivityViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
"""ViewSet for viewing and editing client's accounts."""
queryset = Activity.objects.all()
serializer_class = ActivitySerializer

def get_permissions(self):
    """Set custom permissions for each action."""
    if self.action in ['update', 'partial_update', 'destroy', 'list']:
        self.permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]
    elif self.action in ['create']:
        self.permission_classes = [AllowAny, ]
    return super().get_permissions()
```

Make sure that permission_classes is a list.