# DRF Viewset remove permission for detail route

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

I have a basic Viewset:

```
class UsersViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (OnlyStaff,)
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

It is bind to the `/api/users/` endpoint. I want to create a user profile page, so I need only a particular user, so I can retrieve it from `/api/users/<id>/`, but the problem is that I want `/api/users/<id>/` to be allowed to anyone, but `/api/users/` to keep its permission `OnlyStaff`, so no one can have access to the full list of users.

Note: Perhaps it's not such a good implementation, since anyone could brute force the data incremeting the `id`, but I'm willing to change it from `<id>` to `<slug>`.

How can I delete the permission from detail route?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Override the **`get_permissions()`** method as below

```
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny


class UsersViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (OnlyStaff,)
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == 'retrieve':
            return [AllowAny(), ]        
        return super(UsersViewSet, self).get_permissions()
```

Comment: Thanks once again. So the effective way to override the permission for a specific method is to override `get_permissions()`, not the attribute `permission_classes`.

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you posted the permission class.

But going off what you posted, it appears that only staff users can have access to the endpoints bound to that viewset. Meaning no other user type/role can access those endpoints.

Going off your question, it seems like you want to setup a IsOwnerOrStaffOrReadOnly permission and over ride the list route function of the ModelViewSet and replace permission_classes and then call super

```
class UsersViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrStaffOrReadOnly,)
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

def list(self, request, *arg, **kwargs):
   self.permission_classes = (OnlyStaffCanReadList,)
   super(UsersViewSet, self).list(request, *args, **kwargs)  // python3 super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

is Owner object permission class

```
class IsOwnerOrStaffOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Read permissions are allowed to any request,
        # so we'll always allow GET, HEAD or OPTIONS requests.
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        if request.user.role == 'staff': 
           return True
        # Instance must have an attribute named `owner`.
        return obj.owner == request.user
```

only staff can read permission class

```
class OnlyStaffCanReadList(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.user.role == 'Staff': 
           return True
        else:
           return False
```

as provided in the comments, your user model must have the owner role. if you are using the django user model you can just do a `obj.id == request.user.id` comparison

Comment: overriding `list()` method does not work, it does not get executed. `IsOwnerOrStaffOrReadOnly` gets executed in both endpoints.

Comment: @yierstem very odd. i made a jdoodle to validate the over riding of a tuple in an inherited class to validate that it should be the case. check this out jdoodle.com/a/GQg. After looking further it seems there may be an issue with overriding perms on a single route. Have a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283797/django-rest-framework-add-additional-permission-in-viewset-update-method