# How to have different permission classes for methods in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a view similar to this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework import generics

class MyView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        # <view logic>
        return HttpResponse('result')

    def post(self, request):
        # <view logic x2>
        return HttpResponse('message_post_template')
```

And I would like the GET request to have the permission class of `IsAuthenticated` and the POST request should have a permission class of `HasAPIKey` from [Django REST Framework API Key](https://florimondmanca.github.io/djangorestframework-api-key/guide/#setting-permissions). How can I do this?

I tried doing `permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated | HasAPIKey]` but that would be too lenient because it would allow the functions to work if the other permission other than the one required is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework import generics

class MyView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    def get_permissions(self):
        method = self.request.method
        if method == 'POST':
           return [HasAPIKey()]
        else:
           return [IsAuthenticated()]

    def get_queryset(self):
        # <view logic>
        return HttpResponse('result')

    def post(self, request):
        # <view logic x2>
        return HttpResponse('message_post_template')
```

Reference:
https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/dff9759555eefef67c552f175d04bb7d8381e919/rest_framework/views.py#L274

Comment: This is raising an error `has_permission() missing 1 required positional argument: 'view'`

Comment: It seems you have error in one of your permission classes.

Comment: No I don't. I fixed the problem using an answer similar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283797/django-rest-framework-add-additional-permission-in-viewset-update-method

Comment: Also this works too: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#introspecting-viewset-actions

Comment: Updated it you can check it now.