# Separate permission_classes for GET and POST method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm developing an API and I'm looking for a way to selectively allow access for a given method depending on if the user is authenticated. Ex: An user can only access the GET method if he is authenticated but users and guests can access the POST method.

Django rest framework has the "permissions.IsAuthenticated" class but affects every method in the Class based View.
Here is my code for reference:

```
class ServiceSupplierApiView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        lista =ServiceSupplier.objects.all()
        serializer = ServiceSupplierSerializer(lista,many = True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {
            'name': request.data.get('name'),
        }
        serializer = ServiceSupplierSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = Supplier.objects.get(id = request.data.get('id')) 
        data = {
            'name': request.data.get('name'),
        }

        serializer = ServiceSupplierSerializer(instance = instance,data=data,partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, id, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object(id, request.user.id)
        if not instance:
            return Response(
                {"res": "Object with id does not exists"},
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            )
        instance.delete()
        return Response(
            {"res": "Object deleted!"},
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK
        )
```

I've tried looking it up, but haven't found an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django-rest-framework: add additional permission in ViewSet update method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283797/django-rest-framework-add-additional-permission-in-viewset-update-method)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this its kinda scuffed but it works

```py
def get_permissions(self):
  if self.request.method == 'POST' or self.request.method == 'PUT':
    return [permissions.IsAuthenticated()]
  elif self.request.method == 'DELETE':
    return[permissions.isAdminUser()] # for example
  else:
    return[] # so anyone can view

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
  # logic

.
.
.
.
```

You dont need to declare the `permission_classes`_
however, I think separating the endpoints would be better
for example send the get to `/suppliers`
and post to `/new-supplier`